# How can you convert a 2D image into a rotating 3D image using Photoshop CS5 Extended? Can it be done?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, cs5, gif, adobe-after-effects

I'm still a beginner to Photoshop and every time I look up how to do this, only tutorials for after effects which I don't have and would honestly like to avoid pop up.

I'd be really grateful if anyone could share with me any Photoshop techniques to get an effect similar to the two gifs I've attached to this question.

Or is after effects the only way?

[image]

[image]

Comment: After effects is not the best option either. It is a 3D program. Try Blender. http://www.blender.org/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in photoshop you need every frame in a layer and make an animated gif out of these layers.

It is alot easier to make those things in a 3d editing program, for instance the pack of cigarettes in a 3d program you can create a rectangle and put the textures on each side. In photoshop you would have to draw every frame.

Comment: This guy nails it.  This would be a monumental pain in the butt to animate in Photoshop and you would end up with far too many layers to easily work with.

Answer (score 0):

This website might help: https://www.3dgifmaker.com/

It can extrude or do other effects.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/112882)